# How far from home, can my robot roam? It has constant step size, and turns by increasing amounts.

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

A robot's step size is always $1$. Between steps it turns right, by increasing amounts: $\frac{1\pi}{2},\frac{2\pi}{3},\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{4\pi}{5},...$

> What is the robot's maximum distance from the origin?

Here are the first 15 steps, starting in the lower-left corner (switching color every three steps, for clarity).

[image]

Superimpose cartesian coordinates, with the first step from $(0,0)$ to $(0,1)$. After the $n$th step, the robot's coordinates are:

$$x=\sum_{k=1}^n \sin{\left(\sum_{i=1}^k \pi\left(1-\frac{1}{i}\right)\right)}$$

$$y=\sum_{k=1}^n \cos{\left(\sum_{i=1}^k \pi\left(1-\frac{1}{i}\right)\right)}$$

Its distance from the origin is

$$d(n)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Here is the graph of $d(n)$ against $n$.

[image]

It looks like the maximum value of $d(n)$ is $d(2)=\sqrt{2}$, which corresponds to the red point in the first diagram. But we cannot check the entire graph, because it goes forever. How can we know the maximum value of $d(n)$?

**EDIT**

It would be enough to prove the following:

> Lemma: The circle through three consecutive vertices of the robot's path, encloses all subsequent vertices.

The circle through the first three vertices $(0,0),(0,1),(1,1)$ is $(x-\frac12)^2+(y-\frac12)^2=\frac12$. All points on this circle are within $\sqrt{2}$ from the origin. So we would know that $\sqrt{2}$ is the maximum distance form the origin. But I don't know how to prove the lemma.

**EDIT2**

@Intelligentipauca's comment pointed out that the lemma is false. For example, the circle through the points for $n=2,3,4$ does not enclose the point for $n=6$.

Comment: Why are there two graphs? The function $d=d(n)$ should be single-valued

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro The graph shows one function. $d$ jumps between $n$ values.

Comment: Have you looked at taking and restructuring the addition of the Squares of x and y? It seems that the points converge to a "circle".

Comment: Looks like the midpoints of the steps do converge to some point near to $C=(0.54,0.67)$. If so, the robot will asymptotically lie near to a circle with center $C$ and radius $1/2$, and $d(n)$ will never exceed $\sqrt2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for addressing my concerns with the title and for the explanation of the graph. This is a great question.

Comment: A quick check with GeoGebra shows your lemma is false: the circle through three consecutive vertices encloses the fourth vertex but not the fifth one.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca You're right, for example the circle through the points for $n=2,3,4$ does not enclose the point for $n=6$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identify Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with complex plane $\mathbb{C}$.

For each $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, let
$u_k = i(-1)^k e^{i \pi H_k}$ where $H_k = \sum\limits_{\ell=1}^k \frac{1}{\ell}$ are the Harmonic numbers.
In terms of $u_k$, the position after $n^{th}$ move, $(x_n,y_n)$, is given by the formula:

$$a_n \stackrel{def}{=} x_{n} + iy_{n}= \sum_{k=1}^n u_k$$
Let $b_n$ and $c_n$ be the averages and averages of averages of successive locations of $a_n$. ie.

$$b_n = \frac12(a_{n+1} + a_n)\quad\text{ and }\quad c_n = \frac12(b_{n+1} + b_n)$$

Let $K = \frac{\pi\sqrt{\pi^2+4}}{4}$, notice
$$\begin{align}
|a_n - b_n| 
&= \frac12|u_{n+1}| = \frac12\\
|b_n - c_n |
&= \frac14|u_{n+2} + u_{n+1}| = \frac14\left| e^{i\frac{\pi}{n+2}} - 1\right|\\
&= \frac12\sin\frac{\pi}{2(n+2)} < \frac{\pi}{4(n+2)}\\
|c_{n+1} - c_n| 
&= \frac14|u_{n+3} + 2u_{n+2} + u_{n+1}|
= \frac14\left|e^{i\frac{\pi}{n+3}} - 2 + e^{-i\frac{\pi}{n+1}}\right|\\
&\stackrel{\color{blue}{[1]}}{\le} 
\frac14\sqrt{\left(\frac{\pi^2}{(n+1)(n+3)}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\pi}{n+1} - \frac{\pi}{n+3}\right)^2}\\
&< \frac{K}{(n+1)(n+2)}
\end{align}
$$

So for all $m \ge n$, we have

$$\begin{align}|a_m - c_n| 
&\le |a_m - b_m| + |b_m - c_m| + \sum_{k=n}^{m-1}|c_{k+1}-c_k|\\
&\le \frac12 + \frac{\pi}{4(m+2)} + \sum_{k=n}^{m-1}\frac{K}{(k+1)(k+2)}\\
&< \frac12 + \frac{K}{n+1}
\end{align}
$$
which in turn implies
$$|a_m| < |c_n| + \frac12 + \frac{K}{n+1}$$

For $n = 55$, the expression on RHS $\sim
1.399210680593634 < \sqrt{2} = |a_{2}|$. This means for all $m \ge 55$, $a_m$ is closer to origin than $a_2$.
By brute force, one can verify $|a_1|, |a_3|,\ldots |a_{54}|$ are all smaller than $\sqrt{2}$. This means $\sqrt{2}$ is indeed the maximum distance from origin.

---

**Notes**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - For any $\frac{\pi}{2} \ge u > v> 0$, let $u = p + q$ and $v = p-q$, we have
  $$\begin{align}|e^{iv} - 2 + e^{-iu}|
  &= |e^{ip} - 2e^{iq} + e^{-ip}|\\
  &= 2\sqrt{(\cos(p) - \cos(q))^2 + \sin(q)^2}\\
  &= \sqrt{\left(4\sin\frac{u}{2}\sin\frac{v}{2}\right)^2 + (2\sin(q))^2}\\
  &\le \sqrt{(uv)^2 + (2q)^2}\\
  &= \sqrt{(uv)^2 + (u-v)^2}
  \end{align}
  $$

Comment: Wow, amazing! (In your second line, in the definition of $H_k$, I think there's a typo, should be $\frac{1}{\ell}$ ?)

Comment: that's a typo, fixed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the part called "Notes". Say $p=0.3\pi$ and $q=0.2\pi$. We have $|e^{ip} - 2e^{iq} + e^{-ip}|\approx 1.26$, $2\sqrt{(\cos(p) - \cos(q))^2 + \sin(q)^2}\approx1.06$, $2\sqrt{(1-\cos(q))^2 + \sin(q)^2}\approx1.66$, $4\sin\frac{q}{2}\approx1.24$.

Comment: Hmm.. the inequality is broken at the part $2\sqrt{(\cos(p) - \cos(q))^2 + \sin(q)^2} \le 2\sqrt{(1-\cos(q))^2 + \sin(q)^2}$, need to fix that.

Comment: @Dan fixed but with a worst bound from $30$ to $76$. I remember I once have  something better than this before I "improve" too much to get that wrong inequality.

Comment: improve bound back down to 55. this should be close to what one can get for this approach.

Answer (score 4):

**Compute Alternating Points**

Let
$$
\begin{align}
f(n)
&=\sum_{k=1}^ne^{-i\pi(k-H_k)}\tag{1a}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^ke^{i\pi H_k}\tag{1b}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ definition
$\text{(1b):}$ $e^{i\pi}=-1$

Then
$$
\begin{align}
f(2n)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(e^{i\pi H_{2k}}-e^{i\pi H_{2k-1}}\right)\tag{2a}\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n\left(e^{i\pi H_{2k}}-e^{i\pi H_{2k-2}}+\delta_{2k-1}\right)\tag{2b}\\
&=-\frac12+\frac12e^{i\pi H_{2n}}+\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n\delta_{2k-1}\tag{2c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ add the terms $2$ at a time
$\text{(2b):}$ $\delta_{2k-1}=2\left(e^{i\pi H_{2k}}-e^{i\pi H_{2k-1}}\right)-\left(e^{i\pi H_{2k}}-e^{i\pi H_{2k-2}}\right)$
$\phantom{\text{(2b): }\delta_{2k-1}}=e^{i\pi H_{2k-1}}\left(e^{i\frac\pi{2k}}-2+e^{-i\frac\pi{2k-1}}\right)$
$\text{(2c):}$ telescoping series

Likewise,
$$
\begin{align}
f(2n+1)
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^n\left(e^{i\pi H_{2k}}-e^{i\pi H_{2k+1}}\right)\tag{3a}\\
&=1-\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n\left(e^{i\pi H_{2k+1}}-e^{i\pi H_{2k-1}}+\delta_{2k}\right)\tag{3b}\\
&=\frac12-\frac12e^{i\pi H_{2n+1}}-\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n\delta_{2k}\tag{3c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a):}$ $-e^{i\pi H_1}=1$
$\text{(3b):}$ $\delta_{2k}=2\left(e^{i\pi H_{2k+1}}-e^{i\pi H_{2k}}\right)-\left(e^{i\pi H_{2k+1}}-e^{i\pi H_{2k-1}}\right)$
$\phantom{\text{(3b): }\delta_{2k}}=e^{i\pi H_{2k}}\left(e^{i\frac\pi{2k+1}}-2+e^{-i\frac\pi{2k}}\right)$
$\text{(3c):}$ telescoping series

---

**Bound the Errors**

We can unify $\delta_{2k-1}$ and $\delta_{2k}$ as
$$
\begin{align}
\delta_k
&=e^{i\pi H_k}\left(e^{i\frac\pi{k+1}}-2+e^{-i\frac\pi{k}}\right)\tag{4a}\\
&=e^{i\pi H_k}\left(\left(e^{i\frac\pi{k}}-2+e^{-i\frac\pi{k}}\right)+\left(e^{i\frac\pi{k+1}}-e^{i\frac\pi{k}}\right)\right)\tag{4b}\\
&=e^{i\pi H_k}\left(-4\sin^2\left(\frac\pi{2k}\right)-2ie^{i\frac{\pi(2k+1)}{2k(k+1)}}\sin\left(\frac\pi{2k(k+1)}\right)\right)\tag{4c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a):}$ simplify $\text{(2b)}$ and $\text{(3b)}$
$\text{(4b):}$ algebraic manipulation
$\text{(4c):}$ $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$

The triangle inequality and $\text{(4c)}$ give the bound
$$
|\delta_k|\le\frac{\pi^2+\pi}{k^2}\tag5
$$
Thus, the sum of $\delta_k$ converges absolutely. In particular,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\delta_k
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left[\left(e^{i\pi H_{k-1}}-e^{i\pi H_k}\right)-\left(e^{i\pi H_k}-e^{i\pi H_{k+1}}\right)\right]\tag{6a}\\
&=\left(e^{i\pi H_0}-e^{i\pi H_1}\right)-\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(e^{i\pi H_k}-e^{i\pi H_{k+1}}\right)\tag{6b}\\[3pt]
&=2\tag{6c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(6a):}$ expand on $\text{(4a)}$
$\text{(6b):}$ telescoping series
$\text{(6c):}$ $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\left(e^{i\pi H_k}-e^{i\pi H_{k+1}}\right)=0$

Equation $(6)$ implies that
$$
\begin{align}
c
&=-\frac12+\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty\delta_{2k-1}\tag{7a}\\
&=+\frac12-\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty\delta_{2k}\tag{7b}
\end{align}
$$
Computation gives $c=0.669989-0.541347i$, giving $|c|=0.861361$.

---

**The Partial Sums Tend to a Circle**

Combining $(2)$ and $\text{(7a)}$, we get
$$
f(2n)=c+\frac12e^{-i\pi(2n-H_{2n})}-\frac12\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\delta_{2k-1}\tag8
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac12\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty|\delta_{2k-1}|
&\le\frac12\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{\pi^2+\pi}{(2k-1)^2}\tag{9a}\\
&\le\frac{\pi^2+\pi}8\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\left(\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k\right)\tag{9b}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2+\pi}{8n}\tag{9c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(9a):}$ apply $(5)$
$\text{(9b):}$ $\frac1{(2k-1)^2}\le\frac14\left(\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k\right)$
$\text{(9c):}$ telescoping series

Combining $(3)$ and $\text{(7b)}$, we get
$$
f(2n+1)=c+\frac12e^{-i\pi(2n+1-H_{2n+1})}+\frac12\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\delta_{2k}\tag{10}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac12\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty|\delta_{2k}|
&\le\frac12\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{\pi^2+\pi}{(2k)^2}\tag{11a}\\
&\le\frac{\pi^2+\pi}8\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\left(\frac1{k-1/2}-\frac1{k+1/2}\right)\tag{11b}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2+\pi}{8n+4}\tag{11c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(11a):}$ apply $(5)$
$\text{(11b):}$ $\frac1{(2k)^2}\le\frac14\left(\frac1{k-1/2}-\frac1{k+1/2}\right)$
$\text{(11c):}$ telescoping series

Putting together $(8)$, $(9)$, $(10)$, and $(11)$, we get
$$
\left|f(n)-c-\frac12e^{-i\pi(n-H_n)}\right|\le\frac{\pi^2+\pi}{4n}\tag{12}
$$
That is, $f(n)$ tends to being on a circle around the point $c$ with radius $\frac12$. Plotting the first $100$ steps gives

[image: spiky]

Furthermore, for $n\ge100$,
$$
\begin{align}
|f(n)|
&\le|c|+\frac12+\frac{\pi^2+\pi}{4n}\tag{13a}\\
&=1.361361+\frac{3.252799}{n}\tag{13b}\\[3pt]
&\le1.393889\tag{13c}\\[9pt]
&\lt\sqrt2\tag{13d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(13a):}$ $(12)$ and the triangle inequality
$\text{(13b):}$ evaluate constants
$\text{(13c):}$ evaluate at $n=100$
$\text{(13d):}$ $\sqrt2=1.4142136$

Looking at the plot for $n\le100$, other than $f(2)$, we have $|f(n)|\lt\sqrt2$.